# Memory Deallocation in Circular Singly Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, circular-list

I'm currently refreshing my knowledge on data structures. Today I've decided to take a look at the Linked Lists. I've finished the basic concepts of singly and doubly linked lists. However I've encountered a small problem when I was implementing circular singly linked list in C.

After creating the circular singly linked list with 3 nodes and printing its hierarchy, I wanted to deallocate the memory of the nodes. However whenever I try to run the code, an exception gets thrown. From what I've understood, the problem is related to the line `free(one);`. As you can see in my code, I even tried to break the links between the nodes beforehand. What is the reason behind this problem, is it because I'm freeing the memory in a circular linked list in a wrong way? If not, what method should be followed to get rid of this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct NodeSL nodeSL;

struct NodeSL{
    int data;
    nodeSL *next;
};

void circularLinkedList();

int main(){

    /* Circular Link List Example */
    circularLinkedList();

    return 0;
}

void circularLinkedList(){
    /* Initializing the nodes. */
    nodeSL *head,*one,*two,*three;

    /* Allocating the memory. */
    one=(nodeSL*)malloc(sizeof(nodeSL));
    two=(nodeSL*)malloc(sizeof(nodeSL));
    three=(nodeSL*)malloc(sizeof(nodeSL));

    /* Assigning data values. */
    one->data=1;
    two->data=2;
    three->data=3;

    /* Connecting the nodes. */
    one->next=two;
    two->next=three;
    three->next=one;

    /* Saving the address of the first node in head. */
    head=one;

    nodeSL *p;
    int flag=1;
    p=(nodeSL*)malloc(sizeof(nodeSL));
    p=head;
    printf("THIS IS AN EXAMPLE OF A CIRCULAR LINKED LIST!\n");
    printf("Head has the address %u\n",head);
    while (flag) {
        printf("Data: %d",p->data);
        printf("\tAdress: %u",p);
        printf("\tPoints Forward to the Address: %u\n",p->next);  
        p=p->next;
        if(p==one)
        {
            flag=0;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    /* Deallocating the memory. */
    three->next=NULL;
    two->next=NULL;
    one->next=NULL;
    head=NULL;
    free(p);
    free(two);
    free(three);
    free(one);
}
```

Comment: I suggest running valgrind to track memory allocation problems

Comment: Noted. I'm currently coding in Visual Studio Code. I've found out that it has its own memory tracker feature. In any case, I will make sure to install valgrind to my Ubuntu. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are falling into a classic trap that some beginners encounter when using pointers.

```
nodeSL *p;
p = malloc(sizeof(nodeSL));
p = head;

// ...

free(p)
```

You forget that a pointer is just a number that references some memory location.  If you want to use a pointer (in this case, `p`) to iterate over your list, you do NOT need to request memory from the system.

In short, what you have here is a double-free.  You free `p`, and then later you free `one`, which is the same value that `p` has after your loop.  If you used a debugger, you would see the error on this line.

Furthermore, you allocated memory, stored it in `p` and immediately *leaked* that memory by storing a different value in `p`.

So, just don't do this, and you'll be fine.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I have been coding non-stop for the last 6.5 hours and I think I might have suffered  "brain fatigue".  Now that I see it, I don't  know why I've requested memory for that pointer. I guess I thought that pointer was a node by mistake. And since I thought it was a node I tried to free it, not realizing what you've just said - p is also pointing to one-.  Finally, to be honest, this is the first time I'm learning the concept of "leak" from you :) I'm also a very new to the dynamic memory allocation usage. I will make sure to check more on this topic. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You set `head` equal to `one`. Then you set `p` equal to `head`, which therefore sets `p` equal to `one`. Then you `free(p)` but also `free(one)`. So you free an allocated block that you already freed.

Also, this code is mystifying:

```
    p=(nodeSL*)malloc(sizeof(nodeSL));
    p=head;
```

Why do you allocate a new node just to then change `p` to point to `head` and leak the node you just pointlessly allocated? Do you want `p` to point to the node that `head` already points to or do you want `p` to point to the newly-allocated node? Make up your mind.

Comment: Exactly! That solved the problem. I now see how sill what I was trying to do. Also for the "mystifying code" part, I think I just forgot that I was dealing with a pointer, and assumed p was a node, so I tried to allocate memory for that. Also you beat @Louis Go. Way to go! :) (Many thanks for the quick reply)

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible errors here.

1. `p` is `head` and `head` is `one`, and freeing `p` and `one` means deallocate a pointer twice.

```
    /* Saving the address of the first node in head. */
    head=one;
```

2. Memory leaked by allocating it and immediately assign to it again.

```
    p=(nodeSL*)malloc(sizeof(nodeSL));
    p=head; // p is leaked.
```

I presume you actually wants `p->next = head`.

Comment: I beat you by 23 seconds.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I beat you by guessing OP's intent! :)

Comment: It's not a race :P

Comment: @paddy More like a party :)

Comment: You've nailed it. I've failed to see that both p and head was pointing to "one". Also I think I thought p as a node for a second, so that's why allocated memory for it., then I forgot to delete it once I started working on the while loop. Many thanks for the quick answer!